# Capture the value and append the result of a function

Tags: python, regex

I have a working code which is doing what I need to do for now, but would like to see if I can make it more generic.

I have a pattern which looks like:

```
key_name = ABC/XYZ/
```

Then I do:

```
re.sub(r'(\_b)?(\/(\w+\/\d+\S+)?\s)',key_name,contents)
```

and it works fine with the final result looking something like:

```
key_name = ABC/XYZ/daily/2015-01-05_
```

which is how I need it to look as.

But the regular expression pattern doesn't work if the string is:

```
 key_name = ABC/XYZ
```

So I am now trying to get a pattern which will basically capture the whole value part. (ABC/XYZ/ or ABC/XYZ or anything after =) and add the value of key_name function.

Comment: Are you trying to join two paths together?  If so, os.path.join() will take care of the logic you're trying to work out.

Comment: Not a path actually. Its a value which is coming from a  function. I want to append the function return value to the value of key_name.

Comment: Are you just trying to append to the string?  Do you need to add that slash if it's not there?  I guess I just don't understand why you are using a RE at all in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

For the example you posted:

```
if not key_name.endswith("/"):
    key_name += "/"
key_name += contents
```